# Growth Rate for daily data

Tags: r, prediction, rate

I have a data for selling some product and I would like to calculate the growth rate of this data such that `N_win` and `N_lose` are the win and lose over a period of time 1-19 March. Also, I would like to predict the growth rate and win and lose?

```
        Date N_win N_lose tot1 tot2
1  2018-03-01     0      0    0    0
2  2018-03-02     1      0    1    1
3  2018-03-03     0      0    1    1
4  2018-03-04     1      0    2    2
5  2018-03-05     3      0    5    5
6  2018-03-06     0      0    5    5
7  2018-03-07     2      0    7    7
8  2018-03-08     4      0   11   11
9  2018-03-09     4      0   15   15
10 2018-03-10     5      0   20   20
11 2018-03-11     1      1   21   20
12 2018-03-12    24      1   45   44
13 2018-03-13    41      1   86   85
14 2018-03-14    17      2  103  101
15 2018-03-15    15      3  118  115
16 2018-03-16    15      6  133  127
17 2018-03-17    38      6  171  165
18 2018-03-18    67      6  238  232
```

I tried to apply this function but it seems not working

```
Growthrate = function(x1,x2, n){
  gr = (x2/x1)^(1/n)-1
  return(gr)
}
GR = NULL
for(i in 1:length(DF[,1])){
  GR[i] = Growthrate(DF[i,2],DF[i+1,2], sum(i))
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your best attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I tried this but it seems not working Growthrate = function(x1,x2, n){
`Growthrate = function(x1,x2, n){
  gr = (x2/x1)^(1/n)-1
  return(gr)
}
GR = NULL
for(i in 1:length(DF[,1])){
  GR[i] = Growthrate(DF[i,2],DF[i+1,2], sum(i))
}`

Comment: Please edit the question and add this.